# Triggering two separate events on mouseover in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 bar chart with the associated data points displayed as text on top of each bar. I want to display the text only on mouseover and also make the bar have a different fill color. So, essentially, on mouseover, the bar has to be styled to have a different fill color and the text opacity should go to 1 (from '0').

I am having trouble effecting two separate events on mouseover. I have given an index_value attribute to both elements in order to use d3.select(this).attr(index_value). But my mouseover function does not work. I have no idea why. Here's my relevant code section.

The bar chart

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr('data-value', function(d){return d[region]})
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.year); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[region]); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d[region]); })
    .attr("fill", color)
    .attr("index_year", function(d, i) { return "index-" + d.year; })
    .attr("class", function(d){return "bar " + "bar-index-" + d.year;})
    .attr("color_value", color)
    .on('mouseover', synchronizedMouseOver)
    .on("mouseout", synchronizedMouseOut);
```

The text overlay

```
svg.selectAll(".bartext")
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append("text")
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .attr("x", function(d,i) {
        return x(d.year)+x.rangeBand()/2;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d,i) {
        return height - (height - y(d[region])) - yTextPadding;
    })
    .text(function(d){
         return d3.format(prefix)(d3.round(d[region]));
    })
    .attr("index_year", function(d, i) { return "index-" + d.year; })
    .attr("class", function(d){return "bartext " + "label-index-" + d.year;})
    .on("mouseover", synchronizedMouseOver)
    .on("mouseout", synchronizedMouseOut);
```

And the mouseover function

```
var synchronizedMouseOver = function() {
      var bar = d3.select(this);
      console.log(bar);
      var indexValue = bar.attr("index_year");

      var barSelector = "." + "bar " + "bar-" + indexValue;
      var selectedBar = d3.selectAll(barSelector);
      selectedBar.style("fill", "#f7fcb9");

      var labelSelector = "." + "bartext " + "label-" + indexValue;
      var selectedLabel = d3.selectAll(labelSelector);
      selectedLabel.style("opacity", "1");

      };
```

Comment: Always better to have a complete fiddle, but one thing I spotted is that the `bar-` and `label-` classes within the class selector are not prefixed with a `.`.

Comment: It sounds like you want the mouse handler only on the bars and not on the text.

Comment: Here's my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ajax5687/6Wh5E/5/
I'm using the d3.tsv method to import the data but I've pasted a json version of the data on top of the js file.
And Lars, I am trying to have mouse handlers for both. If I mouse over either one of them, it should push the other into mouseover state too (because they have the same index value).

Comment: @ajai Have you checked the response? It has the solution for the 2 things you wanted to implement: color change and text display on mouseover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by simplifying your listeners. You don't need to add listeners to both rects and text. Just add them to the rects. Here are the simplified listeners:

```
function synchronizedMouseOver(d) {
    var bar = d3.select(this)
        .style("fill","red");

    var text = d3.select(".label-index-" + d.year)
        .style("opacity","1");
};

function synchronizedMouseOut(d) {
    var bar = d3.select(this)
        .style("fill",color);

    var text = d3.select(".label-index-" + d.year)
        .style("opacity","0");        
};
```

Your two friends here are `this` and `d`, the DOM element for the rect and its data node, respectively.

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/haA49/) with the behavior that you desire.